# What is the origin of "rings a bell"?

Tags: etymology, phrases

Where does the expression "rings a bell" come from?

e.g.

> Bob: Have we met before?
>
> Geoff: Well, your face *rings a bell*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=bell):

> To ring a bell "awaken a memory" (1934) is perhaps a reference to [Pavlovian experiments](http://www.nobelprize.org/educational/medicine/pavlov/readmore.html).

Here's an excerpt from that last linked page:

> Pavlov became interested in studying reflexes when he saw that the dogs drooled without the proper stimulus. Although no food was in sight, their saliva still dribbled. It turned out that the dogs were reacting to lab coats. Every time the dogs were served food, the person who served the food was wearing a lab coat. Therefore, the dogs reacted as if food was on its way whenever they saw a lab coat.
>
> In a series of experiments, Pavlov then tried to figure out how these phenomena were linked. For example, he struck a bell when the dogs were fed. If the bell was sounded in close association with their meal, the dogs learnt to associate the sound of the bell with food. After a while, at the mere sound of the bell, they responded by drooling.

Another possible origin is the one [this page](http://www.joe-ks.com/phrases/phrasesR.htm) advocates:

> There are many bells that ring to remind or instruct us to do things: doorbell (open the door), telephone bell (pick up the phone), school bell (come to class), toaster bell (take out the toast), and the clothes dryer bell (take out the clothes). So, if something such as a face, a name, a number, or a date "rings a bell," it causes you to remember something.

To counter the tiresomely inaccurate Google Ngrams, I've decided to do some research using the [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) corpus:

[image]

The first idiomatic usage listed dates from 1941:

> Next time they hear the name Sammy Glick it rings a bell in their brains.

I googled the phrase, and the only result (Google books) was the [link to Budd Schulberg's 1941 short story](http://books.google.com/books?id=eSbBDWgqcgYC&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=%22Next%20time%20they%20hear%20the%20name%20Sammy%20Glick%20it%20rings%20a%20bell%20in%20their%20brains.%22&source=bl&ots=R78Cz8k_BI&sig=QOQY2L_UqVY_kEHwPXY4mLTvzoM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OrFgT-jhCKP40gH9m9G-Bw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Next%20time%20they%20hear%20the%20name%20Sammy%20Glick%20it%20rings%20a%20bell%20in%20their%20brains.%22&f=false).

To my way of thinking, the *in their brains* is significant in determining the age of the phrase.  It sounds a lot like the phrase was new at the time, since the writer felt the need to explain it a little.

By the next usage listed, in 1943, *rings a bell* was used as it is today, with no quantifier phrase.  After these instances, the idiomatic usage occurs often.

Another point in the Pavlov theory's favor is the fact that the number of occurrences jumps after the 1930s.  I tested the corpus by searching for the word "the":

[image]

While 1810 and 1820 had much smaller numbers (69742 and 433985), the number for each decade resides pretty consistently between a million and one and a half million instances.  This shows the extent of the corpus.

Comment: Not convinced by the Pavlov theory, I'm afraid. Seems a bit of a stretch to think that these experiments with dogs and food penetrated into general society enough to create a common phrase.

Comment: On the contrary, that experiment was very popular among laymen, and still is.  Most people know about Pavlov.

Comment: Neither proposal makes much sense to me. Pavlov's bell didn't remind dogs that they were hungry, it informed them that food was available. Similarly, a door bell doesn't remind someone that he needs to open the door, it informs him of something he didn't previously know. That said, I don't suppose that an idiom has to really make sense. The ever-popular Ngram shows the phrase "rings a bell" used before 1830, but without context I don't know if it's in that sense or literal. It does increase dramatically in the 1830s, which would be an argument in favor of the Pavlov theory.

Comment: @Daniel. That's not what I meant. Sure, we all know about Pavlov and his experiments, but I don't see why that would cause a phrase to come into common usage. And why would experiments about dogs responding to stimuli signalling food lead to the creation of the phrase "rings a bell"- what happened to the "dogs" and "food" parts?

Comment: @Ubycoz: I agree that Pavlov's experiments are unlikely to have been the origin of the phrase "ring a bell," though that's an interesting theory to consider.  That said, I politely disagree with your assertion that his experiments wouldn't have "penetrated into general society enough to create a common phrase" - I believe they have!  The expression "_like one of Pavlov's dogs_" is oft-used to describe a quick salivation response, or a trained response, e.g.: "_Five years as a navigator in the Strategic Air Command of the US Air Force had conditioned me like one of Pavlov's dogs_." (R.T. Sharp)

Comment: @J.R. Fair enough then. I wouldn't say those are common phrases though- I've certainly not heard of them.

Comment: @Urbycoz: If you Ngrams "like one of Pavlov's dogs," you'll get 4000+ pages of results, showing the phrase used in a wide variety of contexts.  Maybe "common" is too strong a word, but Pavlov's experiment has indeed clawed its way into the vernacular nonetheless.  Maybe you _have_ heard it said before, but it's just not _ringing a bell_ (that's a mere quip to get our side-discussion back on topic).

Answer (score 4):

> Bells such as the type used in churches are large and loud. Their
>   sound can be heard from a great distance. Bells sound a single, clear
>   note so their sound is distinctive and not easily confused. Before
>   electric sirens and amplification systems, bells were a valuable means
>   of signaling people and alerting of important events.
>
> Further, accurate timepieces were not always as available as they are
>   today. Bells were used to signal people of the start of events such as
>   a church session, the start of school, or a celebration. The bells
>   acted as a reminder of the start of the event for people who had an
>   out of synch timepiece or no timepiece. Someone would literally ring a
>   bell as a reminder.
>
> As an aside bells were later used on clocks to mark the hour. A large
>   clock usually in the town square could be heard throughout the town.
>   This clock acted as a master time reference for the town. The hourly
>   bell ringing gave people an opportunity to synchronize their
>   respective timepieces, and early watches required frequent adjustment.
>
> Alternative: There are many bells that ring to remind or instruct us
>   to do things: doorbell (open the door), telephone bell (pick up the
>   phone), school bell (come to class), toaster bell (take out the
>   toast), and the clothes dryer bell (take out the clothes). So, if
>   something such as a face, a name, a number, or a date "rings a bell,"
>   it causes you to remember something.

[Source](http://www.joe-ks.com/phrases/phrasesR.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I have located an early usage of the phrase, in "The Singer Passes: An Indian Tapestry" by Maud Diver (1934).

> But to-night he was chiefly pre-occupied with a trouble of the spirit wrought in him by the phrase that had rung a bell in his brain, by the unheard whisper of some hidden meaning that eluded him

The phrase "ring a bell" is also included in Alfred H Holt's "**[Phrase Origins - A Study of Familiar Expressions](https://books.google.co.uk/books?ei=ryDGVNXSHeuP7AaX0YHQBw&id=Hg9KAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22ring%20a%20bell%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22sledge%20hammer%22)**" (1936) p. 276

The definition given is:

> **ring a bell.** In the sense of "click" (q.v.), i.e., succeed, strike home, make an impression, I believe this derives from the well-known carnival device rather than from a target with a bell in its center.  I refer to the spring-action contrivance that you hit with a sledge hammer in an effort to send a small weight up a slide to a bell at the top. No doubt the best ones are equipped with an ingenious braking arrangement by which action can be slowed up if some Hercules threatens to carry off...

This appears to have been Holt's personal opinion, and he doesn't appear to give any further evidence to support the theory. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the full text, and can only find snippet views on Google Books.

Answer (score 1):

As an old timer I can remember that "ringing your bell" had to do with the after shock affect of getting "clocked" by a impact to the head.  In the case of boxing, a "bell ringer " would be a knockout where the bell was rung to signal the end of the fight. It was often illustrated as such in old 1950s - 60s cartoons.  I second the reference to the carnival sledgehammer strength meter where the hammer strikes the fulcrum and launches a metal hammer up a vertical slide and ultimately hitting the bell at the top. Just as with boxing, the winner is a bell ringer.  It's not a big stretch to see how this morphed into its current sexual vernacular or even financial stock market reference.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I conclude that it depends on the context. 
I got here from searching “what does it mean when the brakeman rings his bell?” after listening to these lyrics of Night Flight by Led Zeppelin: 
Please Mr. Brakeman, won't you ring your bell. 
And ring loud and clear 
Please Mr. Fireman, won't you ring your bell 
Tell the people they got to fly away from here

I recall that, for steam engine trains, a fireman is the guy who shovels coal into the furnace. According to Wikipedia, the brakeman assists the braking of a train by applying brakes on individual wagons.

Bells have been around for about 5, 000 years, and have obviously been used to convey information and to remind people to do something. If the brakeman rings the bell, it means that the fireman should stop shoveling and close the furnace. For a boxer, it means a hard hit to the head. It’s all about context!